# invalid property value in vb6

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vb6

i have a code right here this is for saving records to databse:

```
If mstrMaintMode = "ADD" Then

    lngIDField = GetNextCustID()

    strSPName = "InsertCustomer"

    Set objNewListItem = mylistview.ListItems.Add(, , txtname.Text)
    PopulateListItem objNewListItem
    With objNewListItem
        **.SubItems(mlngCUST_ID_IDX) = CStr(lngIDField)**
        .EnsureVisible
    End With
    Set mylistview.SelectedItem = objNewListItem
    Set objNewListItem = Nothing
Else
    lngIDField = CLng(mylistview.SelectedItem.SubItems(mlngCUST_ID_IDX))

    strSPName = "UpdateCustomer"

    mylistview.SelectedItem.Text = txtname.Text
    PopulateListItem mylistview.SelectedItem
End If
```

the error is: invalid property value in the line with asterisks. ive tried using this code to another database and it works, but for the other it's not.ive checked the stored procedure, it's right, the table fields, also right but im still getting this error.ive spent 3 hrs to find the answer but i culdn't figure it out.

Comment: The error is nothing to do with your database code. It's complainign about the values themselves. Does `mlngCUST_ID_IDX` refer to a valid (already created) column index?

Comment: yup i intializes that one with 7, i really don't know what happened here..they are not equal with "cstr(lngidfield)", that is the problem?

Comment: And you actually have 8 columns in the list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you have highlighted will fail with "Invalid property value" when you specify a sub item index that is out of bounds given the number of columns in the listview.

As the index is 1 based but starting from the second column, with your index of 7, you need at least 8 columns added.